# ical file shows correct date if it is opened on Mozilla Thunderbird but not in Microsoft outlook

Tags: outlook, icalendar, thunderbird, rfc5545

**Ical File Code:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131107T000000
UID:758ACMRJ
DESCRIPTION: Meeting 
 2013-11-07 00:00:00
CATEGORIES:MEETING
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20131107T000000
SUMMARY: Meeting
DTSTART;TZID=CT:20131107T000000
DTEND;TZID=CT:20131108T000000
LOCATION:  Home
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Microsoft Outlook:**

[image]

**Mozilla Thunderbird:**

[image]

Mozilla Thunderbird is showing correct date.

Comment: They also steal candies from babies and cause world hunger. Sheesh...

Answer (score 0):

This is just how Outlook displays one day all day activities. The activity starts at 11/7/2013 12:00 AM and ends at 11:17/2013 11:59:999 PM of the same day. Activity starting on 11/7/2013 and ending on 11/8/2013 would be 2 days (11/7 and 11/8).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is because Mozilla is following Postel's law (at least on the input side ).

Bottom line your calendar does not follow RFC5545 which states that you should specify your timezone thanks to a `VTIMEZONE` object (see [RFC5545 VTIMEZONE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5)) before referring to TZID.

For proper handling you should also consider add a `X-WR-TIMEZONE` property.